# Postfix (Maia Mailguard) relayhost update ignored

Tags: linux, postfix, spamassassin, amavis, clamav

I have a postfix mail server used in conjunction with Maia Mailguard, Amavis, and clamav for spam. I've upgraded the primary mail server and it has a new IP address. I change main.cf and transport to point to the new server 172.17.2.9 in /etc/postfix, then reload postfix. When I look in /var/log/mail.log, "postfix/smtp * relay=172.17.2.15[172.17.2.15]:25 is still the old mail server (172.17.2.15).

**postconf -n** with our actual domain changed to mydomain.com

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
delay_warning_time = 4h
inet_interfaces = all
local_recipient_maps =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 20480000
mydestination = mydomain.com
myhostname = spam.mydomain.com
mynetworks = 172.17.0.0/21 192.168.10.0/24, 192.168.16.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = mydomain.com
recipient_delimiter = ;
relay_domains = mydomain, mydomain.net, mydomain.int, 172.17.0.0/21 192.168.10.0/24, 192.168.16.0/24
relay_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients
relayhost = 172.17.2.9:25
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

**Transport file**

```
mydoamin.com smtp:[172.17.2.9]:25
```

I've checked resolve.conf and the hosts file to make sure there's nothing funny going on in there, all looks fine.

I've reviewed the maia config.php file and the maia.conf file, nothing there.

Where else could the old server IP be set for mail flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I had everything changed that need to be changed:

- /etc/postfix/main.cf
- /etc/postfix/transport
- /var/www/maia/config.php

You then need to run these commands to tell postfix to recreate the transport database and load the new config settings.

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/transport
sudo service postfix restart
```